# Use if statement in HttpServer handler

Tags: java, httphandler, httpserver

I want when user wants `http://localhost:8000/a` the `I am A response` message should display, (and displayed correctly)

But i want when use wants `http://localhost:8000/b` the `I am B response` message displays.

How use if statement in `httpServer handler`?

```
public class httpServerTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/a", new MyHandler());
    server.createContext("/b", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
}

public static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException { // How use if here?
        String aResponse = "I am A response";
        String bResponse = "I am B response";
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, aResponse.getBytes().length);
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(aResponse.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
}
```

It just displays `I am A response` message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
server.createContext("/a", new MyHandler("A"));
server.createContext("/b", new MyHandler("B"));

public static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {

    private String identity;

    public MyHandler(String identity) {
        this.identity = identity;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException { // How use if here?
        String response = "I am " + identity + " response";
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.getBytes().length);
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are referencing `com.sun.*` private classes, so it may not work in the future.  That being said, it looks like you want the [getRequestURI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html#getRequestURI%28%29).

You could then say `if (t.getRequestURI().getPath().startsWith("/a")) { ... } else {... }`

Comment: How can i get client ip address? i use this: `t.getRemoteAddress().getAddress()` but shows: `[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]`

Comment: That is the correct call -- that address is the loopback address in IPv6 (ie you are testing against your own computer or are using a proxy that connects through localhost)